# RSPEC testing a method that's cached in a constant

Tags: testing, redis, concurrency, rspec, sidekiq

In the below code I'm trying to write a test to confirm `Sidekiq::Limiter` receives `:concurrent` however because I have it cached in a constant `LIMITER` my test fails.  Is there a way to test this?

```rb
  class Processier
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    LIMITER = Sidekiq::Limiter.concurrent('analytics', 1, wait_timeout: 5, lock_timeout: 120)

    def perform
      uploaded_submissions.each do |submission|

        #this is where LIMITER IS CALLED
        LIMITER.within_limit do
          ProcessDownloadedFiles.perform_async(*submission)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you add the error/stacktrace that you're getting?

Comment: And how you're testing it? I would expect you can do `expect(Processier::LIMITER).to receive(...)`